# why can't get the web content in www.nasdaq.com/symbol/c/stock-report?

Tags: python, wget

I want to download the `www.nasdaq.com/symbol/c/stock-report` as a file .
method 1:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
url=r'http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/c/stock-report'
urlopen(url)
```

It run into error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "D:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 153, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "D:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 461, in open
response = meth(req, response)
File "D:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 571, in http_response
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
File "D:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 499, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)
File "D:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 433, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "D:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 579, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

method 2:

```
wget -c 'http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/c/stock-report'
'http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/c/stock-report': Unsupported scheme.
```

How can i automatically down it with program?

Comment: Might want to use python-requests

http://dancallahan.info/journal/python-requests/

Comment: When I try to access that URL I get a 403 Forbidden response. Does the site require an API key?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to get from the page?

Comment: It looks like the server checks the User-Agent header. I tested again, sending the same User-Agent as Chrome, and this time it allowed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried `requests` and it works - I get some HTML data and status code 200.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/c/stock-report')

print r.status_code
print r.text
```

But `HTTP Error 403: Forbidden` can mean than server treated you as bot/hacker/terrorist/etc 
and doesn't give you access to its pages.

Your script has to behaved like human using browser - user-aget, cookies, session ID, time of reaction, etc.

Comment: It is blocking by user agent string. It accepts Firefox, but not things like curl and wget. You should probably see if they have a recommended programmatic way of getting their data.

Comment: It accepted `requests` too. But I tested it only once - probably next time it would block me too :) As for me `user-agent` is first thing to set if connection doesn't work :)